# Converting a C++ snippet to Golang

Tags: c++, go

I'm trying to covert the following C++ snippet to Golang, but I'm not having any luck getting the syntax correct.  Here's what the C++ snippet looks like:

```
v8::String::Utf8Value reqStringObj(args[1]);
const char *reqString = *reqStringObj;

char hex[3] = {reqString[strlen(reqString) - 2], reqString[strlen(reqString) - 1], '\0'};
unsigned char requestId = (unsigned char)strtoul (hex, 0, 16);
printf("requestId is: %d\n", requestId);
```

Here's what I have so far via the Go version:

```
reqStr := "somerandomstringthatihave"
hex := []uint8{reqStr[len(reqStr)-2], reqStr[len(reqStr)-1], '\u0027'}

requestId := ?????
```

I'm not exactly sure how to convert the casted `strtoul` function noted in the C++ function to make it work in the same way via the Go version.  Any ideas?

Comment: why are you using the escape character instead of the NUL terminator? Also, why does the Go variant even *need* any terminator? Aren't Go's strings aware of their length? Also, if you had googled "convert string to integer golang", you would have trivially found out about [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)…

Comment: You're right (I wasn't aware of not  needing the terminator, however).  I didn't think the solution would be so embarrassingly simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this rather easily using [`strconv.ParseUint`](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseUint):

```
reqStr := "jfd0jifdgfa"
if len(reqStr) <= 1 {
  panic("reqStr not long enough")
}
requestId, err := strconv.ParseUint(reqStr[len(reqStr) - 2:], 16, 64)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Keep in mind that final two characters of `reqStr` must be valid hex characters, otherwise the above code will panic.